# How change numbers from a list to another one at a certain position?

Tags: python

There 2 lists with 20 elements each

I want to change the first element of the list A with 20º of list B, the 2º element of list A with 19º of list B and so forth, until change the 20º element of list A with 1º of list B.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code you've tried so far, and be more specific about what part of it isn't behaving as you expect?

Comment: I edited the question to put only the part of the problem i don't understand.Actually the problem is bigger than this.I could share the part i did but i don't think it would help to solve this specific part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right, you want to swap the first element of the list A with the last element of list B, then the second element of list A with second last of list B, Then:

```
l = len(listA)
for i in range(0, l):
    listA[i], listB[(l - 1) - i] = listB[(l - 1) - i], listA[i]
```